# Contact form + redirect doesnt work

Tags: php, forms, redirect, submit

I made a simple "name and email" contact form and I would want it to redirect to "page2.html" after the information has been submitted.

I cant get it to work.

This is the html part I made for the submission form. Im still not sure what does "name" part stand for, the id part (with the dash) refers to CSS styling. But anyhow, this is how I made the contact "name and email" form.

```html
<form method="post" action="submission.php" name="contactform" id="contact-form">
        <fieldset>
        <label for=name accesskey=U><span class="required">*</span> Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" /> 
        <br />
        <label for=email accesskey=E><span class="required">*</span> Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit-button" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>        
</form>
```

and php part is recycled, i tried entering header with redirect in the last line but it doesnt work, the best it does is opens up a blank page in the browser that prints out the info I entered in the form.

I would like to have the form redirect after the info has been submitted, so...thanks for help, in advance :D

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jqueryui", "1.5.2");</script>
<? 
if($_POST['name']!="" ){


    $headers    = "From: Webmaster";
    $message    = 
  strtoupper($_POST['name'])."
".strtoupper($_POST['email'])."
";
    echo str_replace("\n","<br />", $message);
    $headers2   = "From: Sender Name <email@gmail.com>\nContent-Type:     text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding:     8bit\nX-Mailer: PHP\n";
    $message2   = "Message
";

    mail("webmaster@gmail.com", "Subject", $message, $headers);
    mail("$_POST[email]", "Subject", $message2, $headers2);

    $myFile = "submissions.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData =     "$_POST[name]*$_POST[email]*".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."*".date("d-m-Y H:i")."
";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);

} else {
    echo "You didnt enter anything";
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert("You didnt enter anything");
    </script>
    <?
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute in the form will give the $_POST array is name. E.g., using

```
<input type="text" name="awesometext"/>
```

in a form with method="post" will make the value of that text field accessible through $_POST['awesometext'] in the php script you define in the form's action.

If after sending the email you want to redirect the user to another page using header(), no output must be generated on the page before that. Get rid of all echoes and html output, so remove the html you have at the beginning. You may only have php code without output if you want to use header().

Then you can use `header('Location:somepage.php');` to direct to somepage.php.

Your code would then be:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['name']!="" ){


$headers    = "From: Webmaster";
$message    = 
strtoupper($_POST['name'])."
".strtoupper($_POST['email'])."
";
echo str_replace("\n","<br />", $message);
$headers2   = "From: Sender Name <email@gmail.com>\nContent-Type:     text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding:     8bit\nX-Mailer: PHP\n";
$message2   = "Message
";

mail("webmaster@gmail.com", "Subject", $message, $headers);
mail("$_POST[email]", "Subject", $message2, $headers2);

$myFile = "submissions.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData =     "$_POST[name]*$_POST[email]*".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."*".date("d-m-Y H:i")."
";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

//header here
header('Location:somepage.php');

} else {
echo "You didnt enter anything";
?>
```

The header() needs to be called before any output is generated. The code above should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What confused me in the name attribute is that the form has attribute - name="contactform". I dont see how does the submission.php uses that, is it necessary?

Also, removing echoes and html...could you show what you mean on the example code Ive posted? Im kinda new at this, as you can see :)

Comment: Pasted the code into my answer - see above.
Everytime you get the error message "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..." it means you executed header() although output has already been echoed out on the same page, which is not allowed (and also makes sense - the user should either see something on the site, _or_ be directed to another page.

Comment: Another note: Use `<?php` instead of just `<?` to open the php part. Short tags are deprecated.

Comment: And no, a name for the form itself is not necessary.

Comment: If this answer helped, why not accept it as the right one by clicking the green check on the left? :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = mail("webmaster@gmail.com", "Subject", $message, $headers);
$b = mail("$_POST[email]", "Subject", $message2, $headers2);

if($a && $b)
{
  echo '<script>document.location="page2.html"; </script>'
}
```

Comment: I get the error saying "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ... in submission.php on line 23"

Comment: The code Ive entered in my original post seems to be working so since theres time issues, Im going to use that. The only problem is - everytime I submit the form, it blinks a blank PHP page (with the info Ive entered) in the browser and then redirects. Is there to avoid that php page from displaying?

Answer (score 0):

you cant send php redirect headers if you have anyoutput in your script. either change your php part to the top of the page but you can do in php

```
header("location:page2.html"):
```

or use javascript redirect in php

```
echo '<script>document.location="page2.html"; </script>';
```

Comment: Please note that users may have turned javascript off - also, relying on client side functionality for a redirect is generally not as good as doing with server side with php.

Comment: Ive tried with echo, and it works, but the problem is after I enter the info in the form and click submit - thr browser (chrome) first loads a blank page showing the info ive entered, and then after 1-2 seconds it redirects to the desired page...

Comment: this line is needed edit echo str_replace("\n","<br />", $message);
comment out this to $message=str_replace("\n","<br />", $message);

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below in the function.php and it's working

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'wpcf7_mail_sent_callback' );
function wpcf7_mail_sent_callback() {
     header("location: https://www.example.com/thankyou/");
}
```